# Why is the stationary distribution independent of the initial state in the proof of the policy gradient theorem?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proofs, policy-gradient-theorem

I was going through the proof of the policy gradient theorem here: https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/2018/04/08/policy-gradient-algorithms.html#svpg

In the section "Proof of Policy Gradient Theorem" in the block of equations just under the sentence "The nice rewriting above allows us to exclude the derivative of Q-value function..." they set
$$
\eta (s) = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \rho^\pi(s_0 \rightarrow s, k)
$$
and
$$
\sum_s \eta (s) = const
$$
Thus, they basically assume, that the stationary distribution is not dependent on the initial state. But how can we justify this? If the MDP is described by a block diagonal transition matrix, in my mind this should not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your doubt is completely reasonable. Probably there is an additional assumption that they (both Lilian Weng and [Rich Sutton](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) (pag.269)) do not make explicit in the proof and that is that your MDP is not only stationary, but also **ergodic**. A particular property of those systems is that the probability of eventually reaching a state $s$ from a starting point $s_0$ is 1. In such a case it is clear that $\eta(s)$ exists and is independent of any $s_0$ chosen.

Clearly, an MDP with block-diagonal transition matrix does not satisfy such an assumption since the starting point completely restricts those states you can reach in an infinite time.

What I do not understand is why Rich Sutton does mention ergodicity as a necessary condition in the case of a "continuing task", as opposed to "episodic tasks" (pag.275). For me, their proof requires this condition in both cases.

As an additional note, I also think that Lilian Weng does not really explain why we should buy that from the initial reasonable definition $J(\theta)=\sum_\mathcal S d^{\pi_\theta}(s)V^{\pi_\theta}(s)$ we should accept the much simpler one $J(\theta)=V^{\pi_\theta}(s_0)$. I guess the only reason is that the gradient of the initial expression does require to know the gradient of $d^{\pi_\theta}(s)$ and so you would be accepting the approximation:

$$\nabla_\theta J(\theta)=\nabla_\theta\left(\sum_\mathcal S d^{\pi_\theta}(s)V^{\pi_\theta}(s)\right)\approx\sum_\mathcal S d^{\pi_\theta}(s)\nabla_\theta V^{\pi_\theta}(s),$$

where the last term is just $\nabla_\theta V^{\pi_\theta}(s_0)$ under the ergodicity assumption.

Comment: Yes, the second part you mentioned left me also a bit confused. I don't quite see why $\sum d^\pi (s) V^\pi (s) = V^\pi (s_0) $ should be true, even if the system is ergodic. Generally, $V^\pi(s_0)$ makes more sense to me since in practice we always start from $s_0$ and don't sample $s_0$ from $d^\pi (s)$.

Comment: I'm not really saying that the expected value of $V^{\pi}(s)$ is $V^\pi(s_0)$. What is true (if the system is ergodic) is that the expected value of $\nabla V^{\pi}(s)$ is $ \nabla V^\pi(s_0)$, given that the gradient is the same for all states since $\eta(s)$ does not depend on $s_0$.

Comment: About what performance metric is better, I consider that usually you want your policy to be robust, so you not only want to consider one single $s_0$. What happens then if by some perturbance your agent is forced to start in a different state? At least you should consider an initial distribution $\rho(s_0)$. This is done in the TRPO paper, for example.